# Why isnt my inheritance working?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

`LivingThing.call` isn't working. The only property that's created on object creation is the description property. - why? I've checked this multiple times but something keeps eluding me.

```
    function LivingThing(name,sex,distance,attributes,health,level=1){
        this.name=name;
        this.sex=sex;
        this.distance= distance;
        this.attributes=attributes;
        this.health=health;
        this.level= level;
    }
    function Animal(name,sex,distance,description,attributes,health,level){
        LivingThing.call(name,sex,distance,attributes,health,level);
        this.description= description;
    }
    Animal.prototype=Object.create(LivingThing.prototype);
    Animal.prototype.constructor= Animal;
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to pass the context argument to `LivingThing`:

```
function Animal(name,sex,distance,description,attributes,health,level){
    LivingThing.call(this,name,sex,distance,attributes,health,level);
    this.description= description;
}
```

Comment: @ramgy-borja "sex" and "gender" mean the same thing here, please stop proposing these edits to change "sex" to "gender", they do not lend any improvement